# all in one wp migration ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED during upload to new Plesk server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, migration, plesk

I have a new Plesk server and I'm trying to migrate https://glassboxgallery.uk over to it using the all-in-one WP Migration plugin.

The .wpress file for the site is quite large (8.6gb). I have changed the max PHP and Nginx settings to allow for the upload of a 9gb file however the upload still stops at 0.18% every time and the console shows: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Here's the settings I have for PHP & nginx:

memory_limit = 9g

post_max_size = 9g

upload_max_filesize = 9g

nginx:
client_max_body_size 9000m

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your CDN, it might have a maximum upload file size policy.